# How to adapt the option wide of Enumitem to nested lists? (with MWE)

Tags: enumitem

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

% PACKAGES LOADING
\usepackage{blindtext} % To get blind text.
\usepackage{enumitem} % To customise lists.

% INDENTATION
\setlength\parindent{40pt}

% ENUMITEM SETTINGS
\setenumerate{leftmargin=*,labelsep=32.5pt,itemsep=3.25pt,topsep=3.25pt,}
\setitemize{leftmargin=*,labelsep=32.5pt,itemsep=3.25pt,topsep=3.25pt,}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \blindtext
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \blindtext
        \item \blindtext
    \end{itemize}
    \blindtext
    \item \blindtext
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \blindtext
        \item \blindtext
    \end{itemize}
    \blindtext
\end{enumerate}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iG2S.png) is a screenshot that shows part of the output of this MWE. The red lines indicate what I would like to achieve. In words, I wish to adapt the option `wide` of enumitem in such a manner that nested texts do not go all the way to left margin, but instead only go up to their bullet / number. **Can anybody please help to achieve that?**

[image: Screenshot]

Thank you all very much in advanced.

**EDIT**: Following cfr comment, I show what happens if one adds the option `wide`; that is, if one replaces

```
\setenumerate{leftmargin=*,labelsep=32.5pt,itemsep=3.25pt,topsep=3.25pt,}
\setitemize{leftmargin=*,labelsep=32.5pt,itemsep=3.25pt,topsep=3.25pt,}
```

For:

```
\setenumerate{leftmargin=*,labelsep=32.5pt,itemsep=3.25pt,topsep=3.25pt,wide}
\setitemize{leftmargin=*,labelsep=32.5pt,itemsep=3.25pt,topsep=3.25pt,wide}
```

Then, the output I obtain can be seen in Picture [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjHu5.png). Clearly, this is not the desired output.

[image: Screenshot B]

I hope this clarifies the issue.

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to use `wide` at all?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The MWE does not use `wide` at all because it does not need to. If one adds the `wide` option to the `setenumerate` and `setitemize` commands, the output is clearly NOT what I desire. In fact, the option `wide` works properly for the first list, but not for the nested ones. The problem is that `wide`brings all lists to the original left margin. Does it make sense?

Comment: Er ... OK. I thought you wanted to use `wide`. I wasn't suggesting it particularly. I was just trying to understand what you're asking, as I am not really clear about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

..I don't think you need the answer after 2+ years, but here it is for someone who are looking a solution for the same problem (like me an hour ago):

You just need to replace enumiitem settings in your initial MWE to this:

```
% ENUMITEM SETTINGS
\setlist{labelsep=32.5pt,itemsep=3.25pt,topsep=3.25pt, wide}
\setlist[1]{leftmargin=0pt, labelindent=0pt}
\setlist[2]{leftmargin=\parindent, labelindent=\parindent}
```

First line sets parameters for all lists (both enumerate and itemize) and all levels, second line (with optional parameter 1) sets parameters for first-level items, third line (with optional parameter 2) sets parameters for second-level items. If you want to set parameters only for, for example, enumerate lists, you can add another optional parameter like this:

```
\setlist[enumerate, 1]{leftmargin=0pt, labelindent=0pt}
```

I also made an [example on overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/kqnzkjdrqqxb). The project contains two .tex files:

- question.tex - initial MWE,
- answer.tex - my suggestion

Also you may want to look at the picture with explanation how the parameters work. Although there is no "labelindent" parameter, but still I find it useful for understanding how to set parameters. That's the picture from [documentation](https://ctan.altspu.ru/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf), page 3:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE! Thank you very much for providing a valid (and only) answer. I no longer have that question, but I'm very happy to see it answered. Thank you very much.